# Umbraco Adding base64 File with SetValue

Tags: c#, file-upload, umbraco

I'll explain the problem right away, but first of all...is this achievable?

I have a **Document Type** in Umbraco where I store data from a Form. I can store everything except the file.

```
        ...
        content.SetValue("notes", item.Notes);
        content.SetValue("curriculum", item.Curriculum); /*this is the file*/
        ...
```

I'm adding items like this where SetValue comes from the following namespace **namespace Umbraco.Core.Models** and this is the function signature **void SetValue(string propertyTypeAlias, object value)**

And the return error is the following

"String or binary data would be truncated.
↵The statement has been terminated."

Did I missunderstood something? Shouldn't I be sending the base64? I'm adding the image to a media file where it creates a sub-folder with a sequential number. If I try to add an existing folder it appends the file just fine but if I point to a new media sub-folder it also returns an error. Any ideas on how should I approach this?

Thanks in advance

**Edit 1:** After **Cryothic** answer I've updated my code with the following

```
        byte[] tempByte = Convert.FromBase64String(item.Curriculum);
        var mediaFile = _mediaService.CreateMedia(item.cvExtension, -1, Constants.Conventions.MediaTypes.File);
        Stream fileStream = new MemoryStream(tempByte);
        var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(item.cvExtension);
        mediaFile.SetValue("umbracoFile", fileName, fileStream);
        _mediaService.Save(mediaFile);
```

and the error happens at mediaFile.SetValue(...).

If I upload a file from umbraco it goes to "http://localhost:3295/media/1679/test.txt" and the next one would go to "http://localhost:3295/media/1680/test.txt". Where do I tell on my request that it has to add to the **/media** folder and increment? Do I only point to the media folder and umbaco handles the incrementation part?

If I change on SetValue to the following **mediaFile.SetValue("curriculum", fileName, fileStream);** the request succeeds but the file is not added to the content itself and the file is added to "http://localhost:3295/umbraco/media" instead of "http://localhost:3295/media".

If I try the following - **content.SetValue("curriculum", item.cvExtension);** - the file is added to the content but with the path "http://localhost:3295/umbraco/test.txt".

I'm not understanding very well how umbraco inserts files into the media folder (outside umbraco) and how you add the media service path to the content service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you **need** to save base64?
I have done something like that, but using the MediaService.

My project had the option to upload multiple images on mulitple wizard-steps, and I needed to save them all at once. So I looped through the uploaded files (HttpFileCollection) per step. acceptedFiletypes is a string-list with the mimetypes I'd allow.

```
for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++) {
    byte[] fileData = null;
    UploadedFile uf = null;
    try {
        if (acceptedFiletypes.Contains(files[i].ContentType)) {
            using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(files[i].InputStream)) {
                fileData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(files[i].ContentLength);
            }
            if (fileData.Length > 0) {
                uf = new UploadedFile {
                    FileName = files[i].FileName,
                    FileType = fileType,
                    FileData = fileData
                };
            }
        }
    }
    catch { }
    if (uf != null) {
        projectData.UploadedFiles.Add(uf);
    }
}
```

After the last step, I would loop throug my projectData.UploadedFiles and do the following.

```
var service = Umbraco.Core.ApplicationContext.Current.Services.MediaService;


var mediaTypeAlias = "Image";
var mediaItem = service.CreateMedia(fileName, parentFolderID, mediaTypeAlias);
Stream fileStream = new MemoryStream(file.FileData);
mediaItem.SetValue("umbracoFile", fileName, fileStream);
service.Save(mediaItem);
```

I also had a check which would see if the uploaded filename was ending on ".pdf". In that case I'd change the mediaTypeAlias to "File".

I hope this helps.

Comment: No need to save as bas64, but I have the file as a base64 string. I only need to save one file so no need to iterate through them all.
My goal is to save a CV which means I need to save either a pdf or a docx(or other word formats). Should I use mediaTypeAlias "File" for all of those?

During this week I'll try this implementation and give you feedback on my progress. Thanks for the help

Comment: A docx or pdf should be saved as a mediaTypeAlias "File" yes. Good luck.

Comment: So I've tested your approach and even though things make a bit more sense I'm getting an error.

I'll update my question with additional info.

Comment: I haven't saved any base64 images in Umbraco yet, so I don't know if that could be the cause. I just post to a controller and read the Request.Files array. 

Are you using a Virtual Folder by any change for your site?

Comment: I've accepted your answer since it is doing what it is intended to do!
The only thing missing now is something like this: "var url = mediaFile.GetValue("umbracoFile").ToString();"

I can't get the url of the file but the file is already bing stored...any idea?
**var url = mediaFile.GetValue("umbracoFile")** returns null

I'll update my question after when I finally get this done.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Once it's saved you mean?
I don't know about that. I used to save the media item, and return from my controller. It might be a bit overkill, but you could get the ID after the mediafile is saved. And return the IPublishedContent object by doing Umbraco.TypedMedia(NEW_MEDIA_ID). Then you could get the .url value.

Comment: Cryothic got it to work with your help! Turns out I didn't need the url and the url is automatically generated. The problem was I was creatingthe item but not attaching it to the item I previously created. I needed 3 parameters. If I'm not mistaken the media type, the media name and the media itself.

Thanks again for your help :)